# Spring Statemachine for implementing Game Logic

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I was asking if it is a good idea to implement my game logic with the Statemachine framework from spring.io, or if I should implement the state pattern by hand? Do somebody has experience with it?

Comment: If you already use the spring stack *and* the framework provided by Spring makes sense fro your scenario, you should use the Spring framework instead of implementing your own state machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with spring state machine project. It has many great features.

If you have a game logic, it means that the states are changed though events -> it is the way spring state machine works.

In some cases, it is easier to implement the State pattern, because the project is designed to support general usage. I find it difficult to implement custom behavior.

I suggest this tutorial as a starting point : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-state-machine

If you want a simple example:
https://github.com/adinafometescu/tutorials/tree/master/spring-state-machine